# env issues when running cron bash script

Tags: bash, cron

I have a nightly report that is executed by cron with the following lines in it:

```
PRINTFX="/usr/bin/printf"
<snip>
${PRINTFX} "%-11s %-11s %'d\n" ${F1} ${F2} ${F3}
```

Crontab entry:

```
[ca-adm@homwpspect01 ~]$ crontab -l
55      01      *       *       *       /usr/local/sbin/CRONSQLEvents
```

My Issue is that if I run this manually as root (i.e. with my login env settings), I get this [CORRECT] output:

```
Date        Event       Count
2013-02-19  0x00010802  516,616
2013-02-19  0x00010D66  351,840
2013-02-19  0x00010D67  351,533
```

When run by cron as another user, I get [InCorrect]:

```
Date        Event       Count
2013-02-19  0x00010802  516616
2013-02-19  0x00010D66  351840
2013-02-19  0x00010D67  351533
```

If it is run by cron, the comma is MISSING from the numeric output.  I remember reading something about use of printf being ambiguous because there is a bash internal function, but there is also an external in /usr/bin:

```
[root@homwpspect01 sbin]# which printf
printf is a shell builtin
printf is /usr/bin/printf
```

Can someone tell me how to avoid this issue with cron versus logged in execution ?
Especially given that I am specifying the /usr/bin/printf in the script anyway ?

Thanks in advance,
Don

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format of a number printed with `%'d` depends on the current locale, not (necessarily) on which `printf` command you're using.

If your script is as you've shown us, you're invoking `/usr/bin/printf`.

On my system:

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
$ printf "%'d\n" 123456
123,456
$ /usr/bin/printf "%'d\n" 123456
123,456
$ LANG=C printf "%'d\n" 123456
123456
$ LANG=C /usr/bin/printf "%'d\n" 123456
123456
$
```

Bash's built-in `printf` and `/usr/bin/printf` (from GNU Coreutils) behave consistently.

You probably need to set `$LANG` in your script to get the behavior you want.

The `%'d` format is documented in the [GNU libc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Integer-Conversions.html):

> `'`
>
> Separate the digits into groups as specified by the locale specified
>   for the `LC_NUMERIC` category; **note General Numeric::*. This flag is a
>   GNU extension.

Comment: Thank you - that is definitely the issue - I can get this working correctly now...

Answer (score 0):

So to get this to work correctly, I will add this line to the script:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PRINTFX="/usr/bin/printf"
<snip>
${PRINTFX} "%-11s %-11s %'d\n" ${F1} ${F2} ${F3}
```